# Score Keeper Does Not Stop At Winning Score

Tags: javascript, html

I have been building a score keeper as a fun project, but when I try to make it stop at the winning score for the game it does not stop. 
Any help would be appreciated!

```js
var playerOne = document.querySelector("#p1")
var playerTwo = document.querySelector("#p2")
var playerOneScore = 0
var playerTwoScore = 0
var score1 = document.querySelector("#Score1")
var score2 = document.querySelector("#Score2")
var gameOver = false;
var winningScore = 5

playerOne.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!gameOver){
    playerOneScore++
    if(playerOneScore === winningScore){
        gameover = true;
    }
    score1.textContent = playerOneScore;
    }
});

playerTwo.addEventListener("click", function(){
    if(!gameOver){
    playerTwoScore++
    if(playerTwoScore === winningScore){
        gameover = true;
    }
    score2.textContent = playerTwoScore;
    }
});
```

```html
    <h1><span id="Score1">0</span> to <span id="Score2">0</span></h1>

    <p>Playing to: 5</p>

    <input type="number" id="winningScore">
    <button id="p1">Player One</button>
    <button id="p2">Player Two</button>
    <button id="reset">Reset</button>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
```

Comment: gameOver instead of gameover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at your gameover and gameOver variables... should be

`gameOver=true`

```
 if (!gameOver) {
   playerOneScore++
   if (playerOneScore === winningScore) {
     gameOver = true;
   }
   score1.textContent = playerOneScore;
 }
```

Also, this should look much better and readable... consider refactoring you eventListener callback implementation. Same applies for the other player.

```
playerOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  if (gameOver) return;
  playerOneScore++

  gameOver = playerOneScore === winningScore;
  score1.textContent = playerOneScore;

});
```

Comment: For the refactoring, would this be just to improve readability or to improve performance as well?